# how to make python Tkinker treeview active without clicking on it

Tags: tkinter, focus

I am trying to make a `treeview` which shows the names of some companies and trying to focus and select a company by pressing the first alphabet of the company name. My code works fine if I click somewhere on the `treeview` and then press any key. I want to make it work without this click.

I searched the internet but could not find any suggestion. May be search was not apt.
My code is given below:

```
first_item_id = None
for i, item in enumerate(ros):
    item_id = self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=item)
    if i == 0:
        first_item_id = item_id
        self.tree.focus(first_item_id)
        self.tree.selection_set(first_item_id)
self.tree.bind('<KeyPress>', self.keydown)
self.tree.focus_set()
sb = tk.Scrollbar(company_f, orient=tk.VERTICAL, 
    command=self.tree.yview)
sb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nswe')
self.tree.config(yscrollcommand=sb.set)
    
def keydown(self, e):
    letter_pressed = (e.char).upper()
    for i, item in enumerate(ros):
        fl = item[1][0]
        if fl == let`enter code here`
            id = self.tree.get_children()[i]
            self.tree.focus(child_id)
            self.tree.selection_set(child_id)
            self.tree.yview_moveto(i / 10)
            return
```

Comment: have you tried `focus_set`?

Comment: Yes Sir I have tried it. Below is my code for your help

Comment: ros = backend.listcoms()
        first_item_id = None
        for i, item in enumerate(ros):
            item_id = self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=item)
            if i == 0:
                first_item_id = item_id
        self.tree.focus(first_item_id)
        self.tree.selection_set(first_item_id)
        self.tree.bind('<KeyPress>', self.keydown)
        self.tree.focus_set()
        sb = tk.Scrollbar(company_f, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.tree.yview)
        sb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nswe')
        self.tree.config(yscrollcommand=sb.set)

Comment: def keydown(self, e):
        letter_pressed = (e.char).upper()
        for i, item in enumerate(ros):
            fl = item[1][0]
            if fl == letter_pressed:
                child_id = self.tree.get_children()[i]
                self.tree.focus(child_id)
                self.tree.selection_set(child_id)
                self.tree.yview_moveto(i / 10)
                return

Comment: please don't post code in the comment section. It's impossible to read. You can [edit] your original question.

Comment: Sir, Sorry that I posted my code in the comments.  I have edited the question and posted the code their.

Comment: You have already called `self.tree.focus_set()`, so if it does not work, there should be code elsewhere that shift the focus out of the treeview.

Comment: You have a syntax error on this line: `if fl == let'enter code here'`. Also, please create a complete [mcve]. You're missing part of the class definition. You're using a variable named `company_f` that hasn't been defined.

Comment: If you bind to root instead of Treeview, your keypress should become global for your application. This does only make sense if you don't use keypresses anywhere else in your app.